# Copy and paste cells in a workbook does not produce the expected result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook where copy & paste is not working as I would expect.

If I copy, for example, (C3:C5) and paste it into (F3) then the result is that (F3:F5) contains the content of (G3:G5). i.e. the contents of the row following the target row. None of the 'special' paste options show any values - *except* the transpose option. The transpose option fills all of the cells with the value of the last field of the range in target+1.

Example:

```
1: |Alpha|Bravo |Charlie|
2: |     |      |       |
3: |India|Juliet|Kilo   |
```

If I select [A1:C1] and copy into A2 then the result is

```
1: |Alpha|Bravo |Charlie|
2: |India|Juliet|Kilo   |
3: |India|Juliet|Kilo   |
```

All the relevant (source and target) cells do not appear to have any special formatting or contain formulas. I haven't been able to find any macros or filters which might be modifying the action.

I have opened a new workbook and tried performing similar action and this works as I would expect.

What might cause this behaviour? (Excel 2016)

Comment: Any formulas in C3:C5? Does it work if you Past Special -> Values?

Comment: @squillman not as far as I can see. It all appears to be simple text.

Comment: Does the Past Special -> Values work to paste in what you expect?

Comment: @squillman no. I've edited the question accordingly.